# How could I access special functions baked into a Custom DbContext through a Generic DbContext which lives within a Generic Repository?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext, unit-of-work, ddd-repositories

Here is my set up thus far:

- Database-First Entity Framework (generates a EDMX)

  - Separated POCOs into a different project
  - Left *Custom DbContext* under EDMX to be used as a bounded Countext
- Created a UOW
- Created a generic Repository (IRepository)
- Mapped each entity into the UOW through concrete implementations of IRepository

  - UOW instantiates the *Custom DbContext* created by the EDMX and passes it along to each Repository

So far all is well.

Now, the problem stems out of that last part. The UOW instantiates the *Custom DbContext*, injects it into the Repositories and everything works... for the most part.

Each Repository implementation takes the DbContext, creates a DbSet and exposes the usual CRUD operations. All Entities are accessible through generics, so if I want to implement say **GetAll()** I will simply return DbSet and it will already be mapped to the Entity .

BUT, when I try to access a Function Import from DbContext within the Repository... I CAN'T.

It makes sense that I can't of course: the generic repository takes a DbContext as input, but it knows nothing of the *Custom DbContext* created by the EDMX, thus, all such functions added into the *Custom DbContext* are not known to the DbContext within the repository.

In other words:

- I can access the Function Imports from the *Custom DbContext* while in the UOW
- I pass the *Custom DbContext* to the constructor of each Entity Repository
- The Repository expects *any* class that derives from DbContext, so the *Custom DbContext* does the trick
- When the Repository tries to access the Function Import through the DbContext is has access to, it can't, because it has no knowledge of them

Obviously I can't just use the *Custom DbContext* everywhere, because I would be marrying the Repository to a **specific** *Custom DbContext*, and I'll be needing more than one since I'm created several Bounded Context.

Alas, **THE QUESTION**:
How could I call the Function Import from within the Repository without marrying it to a specific *Custom DbContext*?

**Workarounds:**

I know I could use reflection, but I'm trying to stir away from it for performance reasons (I know it is not that terrible, but still... the present question is about finding out a better way).

I have managed to get what I needed using DbContext.SqlQuery() to execute the Stored Procedure (which was mapped to the Function Import in the EDMX). Yet again, since I can easily swap Function Imports in the EDMX, I would like to find a way to access it within the Repository.

Hope it all makes sense. I appreciate any light anyone can shed onto the matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how would you know what function to invoke or what parameters it takes. However you can take a look at the code generated for function imports and it basically looks like this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
     .ExecuteFunction<Customer>("Customers_With_Recent_Orders", customerId)
```

Therefore (instead of using reflection) you can just do the same thing dynamically - given that even with reflection you would have to know what function to invoke, you should know the type of the entity you expect and you can use `params` to pass any number of parameters it should be doable.

**** EDIT ****

You can also execute the function as no tracking by using the other overload:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
     .ExecuteFunction<Customer>(
         "Customers_With_Recent_Orders", 
         MergeOption.NoTracking, 
         customerId)
```

Comment: I like the approach, very ingenious indeed, but comparing it to what I have already `return _dbSet.SqlQuery("GetPosts @Language", new SqlParameter("Language", Language.ToString())).AsNoTracking();` it seems like I haven't taken many steps forward. Moreover, with `DbSet.SqlQuery` I can use `.AsNoTracking()`, which becomes very useful at times (for performance reasons).

As it stands I haven't found a way to just call the _imported function_ without having to pretty much reconstruct it by hand everywhere I need it, instead of retrieving it from the EDMX and have changes therein spread on its own

Comment: The difference is that in your case you start re-introducing SQL to your app while EF is trying to hide it. It may be OK - depending on the circumstances. You can also execute function as no tracking by using a different overload. I updated the post to show how to do this. Feel free to upvote support for stored procs in DbContext: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1607971-code-first-support-for-stored-procedures

Comment: I like the `MergeOption.NoTracking` within the `IObjectContextAdapter`. Didn't know that was available.

Comment: I upvoted _"Code First support for stored procedures"_ as you suggested. However, one of the reasons I chose **DB First** was precisely the ability to use Stored Procedures.

My case here is such that I can't have access to such **Imported Functions** because of a **Class Inheritance** conundrum.